# merging two arrays by indexing entries with the first array items?

Tags: python, matrix

suppose I have

```
a = [1,2,1,3,2,2]
b = [4,7,9,5,6,11]
```

I am expecting

```
c = [[4,9],[7,6,11],[5]]
```

as you might see generated sub-lists are at the indices pointed by the list `a`. How would we do in python?

Comment: How would you do it in Python?

Comment: Do you want a solution in Numpy?  You've marked the tag, but `a` and `b` are lists and your final output `c` is a list of lists, which cannot be a numpy array since it is not of uniform shape.

Comment: check.......! @askewchan

Comment: I'm still unclear how you get from a and b to c

Comment: First array a entries are the indices of the sub arrays of c. @mgilson

Comment: @Erogol: will `a` always be increasing by 1 like that?

Comment: Are items in `a` always in sorted order? May it be `a=[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2....]`?

Comment: no it is specific to the example case, I might change it the exp

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> a = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
>>> b = [4,7,9,5,6,11]
>>> for k,v in zip(a,b):
...     d[k].append(v)
... 
>>>[x[1] for x in sorted(d.items())]
[[4, 7, 9], [5, 6], [11]]
```

Comment: I just look to doc as I am a newbie python coder, it says "dict subclass that calls a factory function to supply missing values" for defaultdict and stupidly cannot see what it means. Can you please give some cues about?

Comment: `defaultdict` saves you from having to initialize your dictionary's keys. `d[k].append(v)` would raise `KeyError` without first making sure that `d[k]` is a list (e.g., `if k not in d: d[k] = []`).

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, I'd simply loop over the terms:

```
def combine(a,b):
    c = [[] for _ in range(max(a))]
    for i, elem in zip(a, b):
        c[i-1].append(elem)
    return c
```

which gives

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 7, 9, 5, 6, 11]
>>> combine(a,b)
[[4, 7, 9], [5, 6], [11]]
>>> a = [1,2,1,3,2,2]
>>> b = [4,7,9,5,6,11]
>>> combine(a,b)
[[4, 9], [7, 6, 11], [5]]
```

Comment: I like the idea of a list here rather than a dict like my answer uses ... +1

Comment: @mgilson this will not work properly for negative values in `a` however